# Keyframe function doesnt work properly

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I'm working on a tutorial and am stopped at this simple keyframe. I want to move the figure but the  entire image move :

HTML :

```
<div class= "figuren"></div>
 <div id="skrollr-body">
   <div id="background" class="hello">
     <div class="page page_falling falling_hello" data-mood="hello">
       <p> heyho im nicole bla</p>
     </div>
     <div class="page page_falling falling_hobbys" data-mood="hobbys">
       <p> heyho im nicole bla</p>
     </div>
     <div class="page page_falling falling_portfolio" data-mood="portfolio">
       <p> heyho im nicole bla</p>
     </div>
     <div class="page page_falling falling_contact" data-mood="contact">
       <p> heyho im nicole bla</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes freak-out {
  0% { background-position: 0 0;}
  100% { background-position: 0 200%;}
}


.hello .figuren {
  animation: freak-out 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
  background: url('hello.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: pls provide image url..

Comment: http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/hellobo9mwya340.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@keyframes freak-out {
  0% { background-position: 0 0;}
  25%{ background-position: 0 30%;}
  75%{ background-position: 0 70%;}
  100% { background-position: 0 100%;}
}


.hello  {
  animation: freak-out 1.5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: freak-out 5s infinite;
  background: url('http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/hellobo9mwya340.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/uqtqzt39/6/

Comment: doesnt work :/ the background image moves instead of the picture

Comment: http://rachelnabors.com/alice-in-videoland/book/ i want a animation like the girl is falling